# Python dictconfig not logging INFO level messages

Tags: python, logging

I have python code that looks like this:

```
import logging
import logging.config

LOG_SETTINGS = {
    'version': 1,

    'formatters': {
        'simple': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s: %(message)s'
        },
    },

    'handlers': {
        'file_handler': {
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': 'example-dict-config-log.log',
            'level': 'INFO',
            'formatter': 'simple',
     },
    'console': {
        'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        'formatter': 'simple',
        'level': 'ERROR'
        }
    },

    'loggers': {
        __name__: {
            'handlers': ('file_handler', 'console',)
        }
    }
}


logging.config.dictConfig(LOG_SETTINGS)

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


logger.error('error messages should go to stderr and file')
logger.info("info messages should go to file")
```

The dict configuration file looks ok to me, but code does not seem to be logging the INFO level message. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I realized that my logger has a default level of `WARNING`, and thus will not be able to log `INFO` messages (whose level number is lower than `WARNING`). so in the `__name__` logger, I added `'level': 'INFO'` and that did it.

Comment: Can you please edit your answer to include the changes which you made?